# Apache2 uncaught Exception 500 error

Tags: php, apache-httpd

I have installed Apache2 on my Debian server with PHP and MariaDB. I use PDO to connect to my MariaDB database. But whenever I get an exception but don't try-catch it, I get an 500 server error.

Is there any way to show the uncaught error like in Windows with XAMPP rather than showing a 500 server error?

Comment: Why is there a close vote for this?  This question is about configuring Apache on Debian so that it shows the PHP error message instead of a HTTP 500.  I'm pretty certain that this is within the scope of this site.